# Rspec-rails 4 error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mongoid, strong-parameters

I have an application running in `rails 4.1` using `mongoid` as the orm. I created a model called `User` which has an attribute `email`. I am using `RSpec` for tests. I created the following spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'User' do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      user: {
        email: "rahul@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  end

  it "should create a valid User instance" do
    param = ActionController::Parameters.new(@attr)
    param.require(:user).permit!
    User.create!(param)
  end
end
```

when I run the spec, I get the following error

**Failure/Error: User.create!(param)
     ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
       ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError**

I know this is related to strong parameters but couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require):

> **require(key)**
>
> [...] returns the parameter at the given `key` [...]

So saying `param.require(:user)` does nothing at all to `param`, it merely does an existence check and *returns* `param[:user]`.

I think you want to say something more like this:

```
param = ActionController::Parameters.new(@attr)
User.create!(param.require(:user).permit!)
```

That usage would match the usual:

```
def some_controller_method
    @user = User.create(user_param)
end

def user_param
    param.require(:user).permit!
end
```

usage in controllers.